# как отобрать данные с помощью awk

Tags: awk

я хочу выбросить из данных строки вида
`1 0`
созданные программой uniq -c
для этого я использую awk.
`awk '$1!=1 && $2!=0'`
но тогда строка
`1 1`
тоже не проходит. похоже что авторы awk допустили ошибку. или что я делаю не так?

Comment: У вас два условия, 1-е срабатывает в обоих вариантах.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
awk '$1" "$2 != "1 0"'
```